# How to call activity with switch-case in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation

How to call activity with switch-case in Kotlin ? I would like to use the switch-case structure on the Kotlin as in the photo below.(Java Code)

```
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.navigation_home:
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_adminword:
                Intent a = new Intent(activity_callender.this,Words_List.class);
                startActivity(a);
                onStop();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_myword:
                Intent b = new Intent(activity_callender.this,SaveWords.class);
                startActivity(b);
                onStop();
                break;
            case R.id.navigation_profil:
                Intent c = new Intent(activity_callender.this,UsersActivity.class);
                startActivity(c);
                onStop();
                break;
        }
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: Check out `when`: https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression

Comment: I think you should be calling `finish()` not `onStop()`

Comment: ...and probably you should be returning `true` for all the cases you handle!

Answer (score 2):

You can not, since Java `switch` is unavailable in Kotlin, use `when` or even an `if` case...

```
fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
    when (item.getItemId()) {
        R.id.navigation_home -> // do something...
        R.id.navigation_adminword -> {
            val a = Intent(this@activity_callender, Words_List::class.java)
            startActivity(a)
            onStop() // this method is called automatically, it is no necessary call it manually
        }
        R.id.navigation_myword -> {
            val b = Intent(this@activity_callender, SaveWords::class.java)
            startActivity(b)
            onStop() // this method is called automatically, it is no necessary call it manually
        }
        R.id.navigation_profil -> {
            val c = Intent(this@activity_callender, UsersActivity::class.java)
            startActivity(c)
            onStop() // this method is called automatically, it is no necessary call it manually
        }
        else -> {
            // else case would be the default switch case
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

actually you can do more things with `when`, as return a value and then assigned it to a variable, and so on...

https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/control-flow.html#when-expression

Answer (score 0):

## When Expression (your question)

I would directly return the result of the `when` expression (which returns the value of each branch). In this case, your fun becomes a "one-liner" which can use Kotlin expression syntax (`=`, not `{}`):

```
fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem) = when (item.getItemId()) {
    R.id.navigation_home -> {
        // Do something
        true
    }
    R.id.navigation_adminword -> menuStartAndFinish(Words_List::class)
    R.id.navigation_myword -> menuStartAndFinish(SaveWords::class)
    R.id.navigation_profil -> menuStartAndFinish(UsersActivity::class)
    else -> false
}
```

## Helper Extensions (reuse across project)

I've delegated the `intent` and `startActivity` logic to these extensions:

```
inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.start(
    cls: KClass<T>, noinline init: (Intent.() -> Unit)? = null
) {
    Intent(this, cls.java).apply {
        init?.invoke(this)
        startActivity(this)
    }
}

inline fun <reified T : Activity> Context.menuStartAndFinish(
    cls: KClass<T>, noinline init: (Intent.() -> Unit)? = null
): Boolean {
    start(cls, init)
    finish()
    return true
}
```

Comment: If you need to do something a little more complicated when setting up your intent, you can pass in a lambda, for example: `start(OtherActivity::class) { putExtra("KEY", value) }`

Answer (score 0):

I use **Bottom Bar** in the link below. I couldn't call Activity. I guess because the **onNavigationItemSelected** property does not exist. 
[enter link description here](https://github.com/ibrahimsn98/SmoothBottomBar)

Answer (score 0):

1. if you are moving from **Java** to **Kotlin**, then you will find some
   changes in the syntax part also.
2. In **Java** we use **switch** but in **Kotlin**, that **switch** gets converted to
   **when**.
3. **when** is also used for **conditional representation** but it does the
   things in a **very smarter and easier way**.
4. Whenever you are having a **number of possibilities** then you can use
   **when** in your code.

For example, the code that was written using **switch** in **Java** :-

```
    switch(number) {
    case 1:
      System.out.println("1");
      break;
    case 2:
      System.out.println("2");
      break;
    case 3:
      System.out.println("3");
      break;
    default:
      System.out.println("Number is not between 1 and 3");
      break;
    }
```

For example, the code that was written using **switch** gets converted to something like below after using **when**:

```
when(number) {
    1 -> println("1")
    2 -> println("2")
    3 -> println("3")
    else -> println("Number is not between 1 and 3")
}
```

So for **your question**, you can write your code in **Kotlin** as :-

```
override fun onNavigationItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
        when(item.itemId){
            R.id.navigation_home -> {}
            R.id.navigation_adminword -> {
                startActivity(Intent(this, Words_List::class.java))
                onStop()
            }
            R.id.navigation_myword -> {
                startActivity(Intent(this, SaveWords::class.java))
                onStop()
            }
            R.id.navigation_myword -> {
                startActivity(Intent(this,  UsersActivity::class.java))
                onStop()
            }
        }
        return false
    }
```